# Tesseract application not running on other PC

Tags: c#, tesseract, emgucv

I have created an OCR using tesseract but it is not running on other systems. I made this app in windows 7 (x64) using x86 debug. Till now I was able to run it on windows 8 having at least intel hd graphics. I am unable to run it on windows 7(even with graphic card), windows xp.

I  get an error of initialize in incorrect format
I get an error type initializer for EMGU.CV.OCR.Tesseract threw an exception
Please help me out.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You say, "Till now". What suddenly changed?

Comment: please check you that you have the correct version of .NET on all the machines

Comment: It may require appropriate Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime version.

Comment: Actually i am still trying whatever new solution i can find for my problem so 'till now'.                   .Net framework check, c++runtime check. I even tried to debug my project solution in same version of visual studio but no result